# How to explain all details with 'ls' command on freebsd and what color means?

Tags: freebsd, ls, setuid

I am trying to clone directory with `cp` command and meeting some attributes lost. For example, when I am trying to run `sudo` command from copied tree, it gives error.

```
sudo: /usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set
```

This is what I am abserving with `ls` command:

[image]

I.e. copied file is indicated with different color. But the textual representations of both files are identical. What is the difference and how to show it with `ls`?

Comment: You are missing the -a switch against cp.

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're not identical.

The first file has the permission bits shown as `-rwsr-xr-x`, the second has `-rwxr-xr-x` (`s` vs `x` after the first `rw`). That is to say, the first one has the setuid bit set, the second doesn't. That happens because `cp` by default doesn't copy the permissions, you just get the default `0666` modified by your umask, the same way as you would if you ran `echo foo > file.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

To get information, you can use `stat [file]`.
Each color indicates file permissions.
`raspi001/usr/bin/sudo` has 4755 permission (usually it is set as 6755) `but`heat2/usr/bin/sudo` has 0755!